# about hibernate with oracle

Tags: database, oracle, hibernate

I am using hibernate to map my classes to oracle database. But when I try to insert something ,get:

```
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-12899: value too large for column
```

I used hibernate tool to generate this table, is there anyway I can manually change the setting of the column size?
I tried to set the length="1000" in hbm.xml file and @Column(length=1000) in object class, but those are not working.

Thank you.

Comment: What's the column base type?  Is it correct to assume it's String/varchar?

Comment: My column is String, it would be no longer than 1000bytes.

Comment: Oracle max sizes here: http://ss64.com/ora/syntax-datatypes.html.  What is the data value?  Sure you don't want CLOB or BLOB instead?

Comment: if I cannot extend the column size, I think i will change to clob, no choise:)

Comment: I don't think the column size is the issue.  How big is the value you're trying to stuff into it?  That's how I read the error message.

Comment: I was trying to give 1000, it's string. Now I change it to clob:)  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How large is your actual value? You might consider using a Lob as the max size in oracle for something like a varchar is 4000. You could use the @Lob annotation on the field/setter if you wanted to go this right.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but my column would not be longer than 1000. Is it necessary to change to lob? Thank you!

Comment: Have you actually validated that the database column has a length of 1000? Not just in your code, but in the db itself.

Comment: I think oracle can hold 4000 bytes for it. Now i am using clob:)Thank you!